# Is it possible to list JSInvokable Methods on Blazor Server from Client-Side?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

According to [JS InterOP in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-8.0) we can call .NET methods from JS by calling method `DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorSample', 'ReturnArrayAsync')` where the first argument is the Assembly name and second is the .NET method name.

If we have access to a Blazor server app in browser; can we check the Assembly Name and list all the JSInvokable methods available to us in Developer tools? Assuming we don't have access to the source code.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the requirement at first. And I'm afraid that it's impossbile for listing Assembly Name and the methods which having JSInvokable in Develop tools. In Develop tools what we have are js codes and we can't get what you want when we are not able to access source code.

Comment: @TinyWang I see, I was seeing it as a potential security issue if we can list the methods available and invoke them using malicious input.

Comment: yeah, don't worry about the security issue about it, server side blazor rendering the html content in server side and the browser only need to load the generated html content.